# Discord.py(PyCord) premium commands

Tags: python, discord.py, patreon

I'm trying to make premium commands in Pycord(discord.py fork). I choosed patreon. So now I don't know how can user who is trying to bought premium add his user ID in patreon checkout.

Comment: does patreon have discord server?

Answer (score 0):

Two things here..

Pycord is only a fork, it doesn't have much of its own features/classes added on *yet*. [Here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/) is its docs link and [Here](https://discord.gg/pycord) is its Discord server, and I suggest you do some research on how to handle Patreon rewards.

*For example*: Patreon have a bot that can grant role rewards to users if they pledge to a certain plan, so if I was you I'd consider allowing the Patreon bot do all the work by granting users a special role for Premium Subscribers. After that I would check if a user has said role, if they do you can grant them special access to (in your case) premium commands!